# What should I do to print out the desired sql join result value?( SQL Join first match only)

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have two tables :

I want to use the chart_num value for two tables.

**Table hospital_payment_data**

```
id  chart_num   treatment_fees_difference    treatment_fees_check_division
1        9         200000                            test
2        9        -100000                            test 
3        10        200000                            test
4        10       -100000                            test
```

**Table advenced_payment**

```
 id  chart_num      advenced_amount

  1      9          100000
  2      10         100000
```

**I want result**

```
   if_treatment_fees_check_division         sum_init_amount     test       COUNT  
          200000                               200000           400000       4
```

However, when you send a query, the following results are printed.

```
SELECT 
        SUM(t_join.treatment_fees_difference) if_treatment_fees_check_division, 
        SUM(t_join.advenced_amount) sum_init_amount, 
        SUM(t_join.treatment_fees_difference) + SUM(t_join.advenced_amount) test,
        COUNT(*) "count"
  FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT t_a.treatment_fees_difference , IFNULL(t_b.advenced_amount,0 ) AS advenced_amount
      FROM hospital_payment_data t_a  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN advenced_payment t_b on t_a.chart_num = t_b.chart_num
     WHERE t_a.treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' 
  ) t_join
```

bad result

[image]
***How do I fix my query to get the results I want?***

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements. Your desired result has a column `sum_init_amount` but no indication where that data should come from. In the example code and actual result it seems like the corresponding column is called `advenced_amount`.

Comment: modify complete

Comment: Could you describe what calculation are to be performed, or change the numbers to be different enough to make this more obvious?
The solution is probably to use a `group by` statement instead of the subquery.

Comment: I want to sum the sum value of treatment_fees_differences and sum value of the added_count based on the sum chart number.
However, the added_count should be added one by one, as many as the number of treatment_fees_differences.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you are joining the tables, which will give you two rows in the results, then you are summing the values with `sum(t_join.advenced_amount) sum_init_amount` which is giving double the value you want. 
This is a quick and nasty fix:

```
SELECT 
        sum(t_join.treatment_fees_difference) if_treatment_fees_check_division, 
         MIN(t_join.advenced_amount) sum_init_amount     , 
        sum(t_join.treatment_fees_difference) + sum(t_join.advenced_amount) test,
        COUNT(*) "count"
FROM 
(   
    SELECT t_a.treatment_fees_difference , IFNULL(t_b.advenced_amount,0 ) AS advenced_amount
    FROM hospital_payment_data t_a  LEFT OUTER JOIN   advenced_payment t_b on t_a.chart_num = t_b.chart_num
    WHERE t_a.treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' 
) t_join
```

But that will probably fail in a real world application. 
Try it like this (untested):

```
SELECT 
       if_treatment_fees_check_division, 
       advenced_amount AS sum_init_amount , 
       if_treatment_fees_check_division + advenced_amount AS test,
       row_count AS "count"
FROM 
(   
    SELECT 
      SUM(treatment_fees_difference) as if_treatment_fees_check_division,
      count(*) as row_count, 
      chart_num
    FROM hospital_payment_data  
    WHERE treatment_fees_check_division = 'test' 
    GROUP BY chart_num
) as TABLE1
LEFT OUTER JOIN advenced_payment AS TABLE2 
ON TABLE1.chart_num = TABLE2.chart_num
```

Comment: The output of the desired result value is not possible.